# Will the loot on normal server be same as on the PTR

Tags: overwatch

I was stacking loot boxes to open them all when I reach 100. Some days ago I logged on the PTR. I saw that I had 40 boxes (on normal server I got 47, so the copy of the data on PTR was 2-3 days old) and knowing that it won't affect my boxes on the normal server, I opened them and I was quite disappointed. Now I read this question: [Are Overwatch Loot Boxes Populated When Awarded, or When Opened?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/287870/are-overwatch-loot-boxes-populated-when-awarded-or-when-opened)

I started wondering if it possible that the content of the loot boxes is generated at the time when the copy to PTR was made or the content is carried over from the normal server?

Comment: Likely, since the items are predetermined before hand.  When they copied the data over, that kind of information would likely come with the copy since its a predetermined attribute.  The only thing that sort of discusses this is [this Overwatch](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20753515592) forum thread, which someone pointed out that the OP said they were surprised that they got the same loot (hence answering the question).

Comment: You could always open one on each server and find out. Actually, since you know existing boxes can't have items for characters introduced after you got them, I'm not sure why you're saving them.

Comment: @Powerlord I'm saving them not to obtain future content, but for enjoyment to open a bunch of boxes one after another.